# Why string.Format does not throw ArgumentNullException?

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-4.6

According to MSDN String.Format throws if format is null (pretty reasonable), [link here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx)

But testing says it only does that if the second argument is null as well, not if the second one is populated.

The following does not throw:

```
string test = string.Format(null, "string");
```

The following throws complaining about the first parameter (format):

```
string test = string.Format(null, null);
```

Digging futher with JustDecompile the source code calls the following method:

```
 private static string FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, string format, ParamsArray args)
 {
    if (format == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("format");
    }
    return StringBuilderCache.GetStringAndRelease(StringBuilderCache.Acquire(format.Length + args.Length * 8).AppendFormatHelper(provider, format, args));
 }
```

Which makes no sense as format is null and no exception is thrown. Any hints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, the joys of overload resolution. In that case, you're actually calling [`string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, params object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7#System_String_Format_System_IFormatProvider_System_String_System_Object___) - so you're passing a null argument for the `provider` parameter, which is entirely valid (and means to use the current culture).

That overload is "better" because the conversion of the second argument from string literal to `string` is better than the conversion from string literal to `object`.

If you use argument names to force the right overload, load this:

```
string text = string.Format(format: null, arg0: "string");
```

... then it throws an exception as expected.

Comment: This is why I've tried to get in the habit of passing `default(T)` for method arguments instead of `null`.  Even if you bind to the correct method when passing `null`, there's no guarantee someone won't introduce an overload that breaks your code.  Worse, you may not even realize it for some time.

Comment: This is why overloading stinks. Make people qualify the method name like FormatByProvider. You can always do that in your own method names. Yes your code will be longer. And people will call this quackery. Unit test make your code longer too, and you don't see people saying those are quackery.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks Jon.